# Collapsing the p:treeTable back doesn't move the footer back in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jsf, primefaces, treetable

I am new to Primefaces and using version 3.5

I am playing around with a treetable with single selection mode. I was able to populate it with data but there is a problem when expanding and collapsing node. My page has a footer and the treetable is placed in the content part. When expanding the node, the table pushed the footer down - which is okay, but when it is collapsed back, the footer is not moving up - leaving huge space between the table and the footer.

I am experiencing this issue under Chrome, but works okay with FireFox.

May anyone has a fix on this. Thank you!

Comment: Is this reproducible with the treetable on the primefaces showcase?

Comment: I am using jsf template for the layout and copied the sample from the showcase.

Comment: I guess you will have to provide a stripped down example of this problem if you want someone to look at this and provide some help. Chances that someone experienced the exact same problem and could thus help you without further information are small (imho).